# gettext-common internationalization generating exception

Tags: java, internationalization, gettext

I am working on internationalization, using gettext-commons Library. I tried one simple code, but, its giving me following exception.

Below is the code, most of the part is from that gettext-common tutorial only.

```
import org.xnap.commons.i18n.*;

public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {}       

    String localizedString;
    private static I18n i18n = I18nFactory.getI18n(SampleClass.class);

    public SampleClass()
    {
            localizedString = i18n.tr("Hello, World");
            System.out.println(localizedString);
    } }
```

When I run I got below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Resource bundle not found
    at org.xnap.commons.i18n.I18nFactory.getI18n(I18nFactory.java:255)
    at org.xnap.commons.i18n.I18nFactory.getI18n(I18nFactory.java:178)
    at org.xnap.commons.i18n.I18nFactory.getI18n(I18nFactory.java:127)
    at org.xnap.commons.i18n.I18nFactory.getI18n(I18nFactory.java:116)
    at SampleClass.<clinit>(SampleClass.java:10)
```

What can be the issue.

Comment: Where is the instantiation of `I18n` class ?

Comment: Neeraj, please check. I have added that